# How do i toggle rotation on svg images in Bootstrap 4 Accordion card on click?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, accordion, svg-transforms

I have a svg arrow image within each header of my Bootstrap 4 accordion card. I want the header I open's arrow to rotate 180 degrees while it is open and to toggle back to it's initial state if I close it or open another header. Right now the arrows only rotate while i'm holding down the click then return back to the initial state as soon as I release the mouse. Any help?

CSS

```
.arrow:active {
          
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
         
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
      <h3> FAQ </h3>
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> 
         How many team members can I invite? 
        </button>
          <img src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" class="arrow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
         You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
  team members for the Premium plan.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
    $('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the down (open) arrow as the initial state, you'll want to set any initially closed accordion arrows to `collapsed`, and then use this CSS to flip the image up (open) when the accordion sections are opened.

```
.arrow:not(.collapsed) {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/F1ADjTNU8B)

Comment: thank you again. should this same method work for making the heading font weight higher when opened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS

```
.arrow.collapsed {          
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);         
}
```